# Illegal string offset foreach

Tags: php, api, loops, post, foreach

i have this code, and i get the error when i use foreach on the bottom of the page.

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php
   $data =('https://www.example.com/api/report_advertiser?key=abcd&campaigns=6757955,6781745,6739793,6349821&quick=last_month');
   $data_json = json_encode($data);
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $data);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_json);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   $response  = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   foreach ($response as $value)
   echo $value['campaigns']
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So what can't you understand about that error?

Comment: And how is that different from your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63326083/php-api-post-request

Comment: I did solve that but i get this error when i use foreach

Answer (score 0):

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Looking at this code, you should know that [curl_exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec) returns a string, when the execution was successful, otherwise `false`.

But in the next step you iterate over a string

```
foreach ($response as $value) {
    echo $value['campaigns'];
}
```

You can iterate only over [iterable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.iterable.php) types like arrays.

As it looks like you expect a JSON string you can convert it into an array. Use [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode) for that and pass true as second parameter to receive an associative array instead of an object.

> Assuming you will receive a multidimensional array having the inner loops key `campaigns`, following code will do the job.

```
$response = json_decode($response, true);

foreach ($response as $value) {
    echo $value['campaigns'];
}
```

## Update 1

Using the URL you provided before *(I anonymized because you submitted credentials)* you will receive an error.

```
if (!empty($response['errors'])) {
    throw new Exception(print_r($response['errors'], true));
}
```

Gives out following, so it can not work as you expect, because the data is simply not available.

> [status] => 405
> [code] => 13
> [title] => Method not allowed for this action

Comment: I said, assuming the data is like you tried to parse. Give an example of your JSON and I will update